# Mongoose: How to query sub document

Tags: mongoose

I have the following model

```
var ProgramSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date, default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,  ref: 'User'
  },
  name: {
    type: String, default: '', required: 'Name cannot be blank', trim: true
  },
  permissions: [{
      user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
      },
      roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String, enum: ['reader', 'editor', 'admin', 'requested']
          }]
      }
    }]
});
```

I need 3 different queries. I'm sure if you help me with one of them, I can figure out the other 2.

1. I want it to return a list of programs that a user is either a reader, editor, or admin role
2. I want it to return a list of programs that a user is either a editor or admin role
3. I want it to return a list of programs that a user is **only** in the requested role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I created a new factory by modifying the existing programs.client.service.js

```
angular.module('programs')
  .factory('Programs', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
      return $resource('api/programs/:programId', {
        programId: '@_id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        }
      });
    }
  ])
  .factory('ProgramsSubscribedForUser', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/programs/user/:userId', {
            userId: ''
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

added a new route in programs.server.js

```
app.route('/api/programs/user/:userId').all(programsPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(programs.listProgramsSubscribedForUser);
```

added the new function in the programs.server.controller.js

```
exports.listProgramsSubscribedForUser = function (req, res) {
  Program.find(
    { $and: [ 
        {"permissions.user" : req.user }, 
        {"permissions.roles" : { $in: [ 'admin', 'editor', 'reader' ] } }
     ] }
    ).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, programs) {

    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(programs);
    }
  });
};
```